# how to make vertical scrolling list in sync with view pager

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling

I have vertical scrolling list in Activity 'A' and view pager in Activity 'B'. When a user clicks on an item in Activity 'A' it goes to Activity 'B' for detail. Now user can swipe left or right to view details of next item inside list directly from Activity 'B'.

List in Activity 'A' is endless scrolling, when it reaches to end it loads more items automatically.
I am using fragment which represents one page inside view pager in Activity 'B' which takes the same object as a parameter as in RecyclerView item in Activity 'A'.

This pattern is commonly used for reading articles.

[image: This image can better explain this scenario.]

Now my question has two parts:

First is how to use the same data list for both activities? I want to keep data at one place as both activities using same data, only representation and navigation is different, one inside RecyclerView and other is inside ViewPager and data list is already loaded for RecyclerView in Activity A. Moreover data is also large so i don't want to duplicate data in memory for each activity.

Second is when i swipe next from view pager and go to next item's detail in activity 'B' the recycler view in Activity 'A' should also scroll to next item synchronously, although it's not visible to user. so that RecyclerView can load more items when reaches till end and ViewPager can also behave endless swipe like endless scrolling list. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't understand your question. you asking for how to send list of data into fragment A to B

Comment: @AndroidTeam Actually my question has two parts, first is i want to keep data at one place (in Activity A only) as both activities using same data, only representation and navigation is different, one inside RecyclerView and other is inside ViewPager. As data is large so i don't want to duplicate data in memory for each activity.
Second is when i swipe next from view pager and go to next item's detail in activity B the recycler view in Activity A should also scroll to next item synchronously, although it's not visible to user.

Comment: @AndroidTeam i edited my question now it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Local Database for this purpose. So both activity will access data from DB. Only pass index of item to second activity and onPageScroll listener you can change that index and get data from DB according to page swipe(left/right).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the problem in using database for this purpose is my list is endless scrolling as it loads more items dynamically when it reaches to end after scrolling. This behavior is only possible it if data is in memory. 
As i already have data list in memory i want to use same data for view pager in next Activity. when i swipe view pager list should also scroll to next item in previous Activity (although it's not visible) and when list reaches till end it automatically loads more items in this way view pager also behaves like endless swipe and in sync with list.